# Is it possible to make PDO ignore invalid parameter number exception?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to execute a query with parameters, for not repeating myself and avoid writing boilerplate code I'm using a single associative array that has values to bind for several different queries.

When I execute a query with the array I get "invalid parameter number number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" error, which may be very rational if I wasn't providing all parameters to the query, but is very redundant when I provide more then it needs.It could simply ignore all the unused parameters...

Is it possible to ignore\avoid this exception while still providing extra unused params to PDO query?

Comment: Loop through the array, binding parameters as you go?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make PDO ignore invalid parameter number exception?

No.

I believe that some earlier PHP versions did allow that in some circumstances, but with recent versions I was unable to reproduce this behavior.

Either way, it's better to make your code explicit.

Comment: I guess there is no choice but making it explicit then

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old now, but if you are flexible with the columns the query returns, you could always just make sure the queries all have a NotNeeded column at the end which just CONCAT()'s all the parameters you don't need in that query together. It feels a bit inelegant and wasteful, but isn't too bad in reality.

If you're returning large numbers of rows, you may want to MID(CONCAT(), 0, 0) so you aren't actually returning that much extra useless data in the results.

I just did this for a project I'm working on and it worked just fine - much simpler solution than having to customize the parameter set for each query type. Now I just prepare all 6 query types into an array keyed on the type, and use the type to pick the query and pass in all the parameters without regard for what that query actually requires.

Six prepares, one execute. Quite a bit smaller than 6 prepares and 6 different executes, or 6 prepares, 6 parameter creations, and one execute, though those are also valid approaches.